# In decimal to hexadecimal conversion in c how to get the value for 0?

Tags: c

This must be a silly question in c. I've done this conversion more times. But it seems awkward today that actually what i have written in c dont give me the value of 0.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n,i=1,j,p;
    char a[100];
    printf("Enter thedecimal number\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n==0)
    {
        a[i]=0;
        j=2;
    }
    while(n!=0)
    {
        p=n%16;
        if(p>=0&&p<=9)
            a[i]=48+p;
        if(p>=10&&p<=15)
            a[i]=87+p;
        n=n/16;
        i++;
    }
    for(j=1;j<i;j++)
        printf("%c",a[j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Instead of `if(n==0)  { ..  } while(n!=0)  { ... }`, use `do { p=n%16; ... } while (n);`

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake indeed: confusion between `0` and `'0'`.  Change the first test into:

```
if (n == 0) {
    a[i] = '0';
    i++;
}
```

Also note that your code has other issues:

- the prototype for `main` is `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent, `main()` is an obsolete form, no longer supported in modern versions of the C standard.
- The return value of `scanf()` should be tested.  If it is different from `1`, your code invokes undefined behaviour.
- you do not handle negative numbers.
- hard coded values such as `48` or `87` should be written as `'0'` and `'a' - 10`
- less important, from a style perspective, it is misleading to name an `int` variable `p`, unless you are referring to a prime number.  Name it `d` for digit.
- arrays are 0 based in C, you should initialize `i` to `0` and update the code for consistency.
- major bug: you print the hex digit in the wrong order.  you should iterate on the array from `i` down to `0`.
- you could avoid the test on `0` by changing the `while (n != 0)` loop into a `do/while(n != 0)` loop or equivalent.  This forces the conversion to produce at least one digit, namely a `'0'` for the value `0`.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[100];
    unsigned n, i = sizeof(a), d;
    printf("Enter the decimal number\n");
    if (scanf("%u", &n) == 1) {
        a[--i] = '\0';
        do {
            d = n % 16;
            if (d <= 9)
                a[--i] = '0' + d;
            else
                a[--i] = 'a' + d - 10;
            n = n / 16;
        } while (n != 0);
        puts(a + i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that `j = 2;` comes from the original code, but that doesn't make it right. I think the OP meant `i = 2;` there, otherwise the final `for` loop won't print anything for `n == 0`.

Comment: Another aside: on the whole, it would be best to null terminate the string if the code were going to be abstracted into a function of some sort.  In the context, it isn't crucial, but in general, making sure strings are null terminated is a good idea.

Comment: i used c in gcc @chqrlie